# Populate Java FX combobox with a List<String>

Tags: java, javafx

I have issues with populating comboBox in JavaFX with values in a list. I am very green with UI development so nothing I found online was really helpful to me. Now I have a `Class myClass` with a method `getNames()` that returns `List<String>`. Now I need the names form that method to be selectable from the dropdown menu. I tried something like this in my Controller :

```
ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(myClass.getNames());

@FXML
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
```

but when I launch my program my comboBox is still empty. Of course I also put `fx:id = "comboBox"` in .fxml file.
Did I miss something or should I do that with a completely different method?

Comment: Change `@FXML
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);` to `@FXML
final ComboBox comboBox;`. Do in initialize method -> `comboBox.setItems(options);`.

Comment: I can't declare final variable without initializing it thou...

Comment: Get rid of `final`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ComboBox` is annotated with `@FXML` which means an instance will be injected by the `FXMLLoader`. This injected instance will replace the instance you have created. You should instead populate the `ComboBox` from the `initialize` method (see [*Introduction to FXML*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)).

```
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public class Controller {

    @FXML 
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Must declare myClass instance somewhere
        comboBox.getItems().setAll(myClass.getNames());
    }

}
```

Notice I also made the `ComboBox` generic (and non-`final`). [Avoid using raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

---

While the above is true, your use of `final` complicates things. From some quick testing it appears the `FXMLLoader` does not attempt to inject `final` fields (which makes sense). However, the `ComboBox` you've created is not the same one that was added to the scene-graph. In other words, the `FXMLLoader` still creates its own `ComboBox` which is the one used for building the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

From [Creating JavaFX user interfaces using FXML | CalliCoder](https://www.callicoder.com/javafx-fxml-form-gui-tutorial/):

> The FXML loader instantiates the controller class, injects the fields
>   defined in the controller class with objects instantiated from the
>   fxml document and then calls the controller’s initialize() method.

And

> The @FXML annotation is
>   mandatory for private member fields of the controller class,
>   otherwise, field injection won’t work. However, it can be omitted for
>   public fields.

---

With the code below as mentioned in your question, you're trying to set this field, but afterwards this is overridden by the `FXMLLoader`.

```
@FXML
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
```

You should initialize the variable `comboBox` to something like this:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox comboBox;
```

And afterwards (after it's been injected by the `FXMLLoader`) set the items of this `ComboBox` in this method:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {

}
```